# I am confused by the reason given for a rejected edit

Tags: discussion, edits

The reason given was

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

I am confused because

1. I don't see how it can be read that my edit intended to address the
   author of the post.
2. I don't think it makes sense to add the content as a comment.
3. It seems reasonable to me to expand a very short answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12194230

Comment: Ignore the first sentence.  Read the second one.

Comment: Generally speaking, when you feel like an answer doesn't have the necessary content, then you should post your own.  If you don't want to post your own, you leave a comment letting the author know what's missing.  You should avoid adding extra content to someone's answer.