# Wrongly rejected answer-edit (fixing broken code, plus extra edits to reach character minimum)

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

My answer edit at https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21685710 fixed an objectively broken (misspelled) Qt method call, but was rejected for nonsensical reasons.

"This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit." No I was fixing the answer so it compiles.

Do people use the rejection notice:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

when they intend to say:

> This edit supplies new information not found in the original answer.

? The current rejection message is inappropriate since it's very abstract and doesn't clearly tell editors that adding information is prohibited. ([I am confused by the reason given for a rejected edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322318/i-am-confused-by-the-reason-given-for-a-rejected-edit) appears to also believe the current rejection message is poorly worded.)

---

[Drop the current 6 character minimum for broken hyperlink edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158707/drop-the-current-6-character-minimum-for-broken-hyperlink-edits) suggests making extra edits to avoid the 6-character minimum. That's what I did, and my edit got rejected.

[Legitimate edits of less than 6 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149771/legitimate-edits-of-less-than-6-characters) suggests adding a comment instead of fixing the typo... which adds more work for readers of the answer than fixing the typo in the first place. And the author of the answer is inactive and may not fix it.

---

This is not the first time my edits have been rejected: [Edit rejected, for adding extra information beyond single-character typo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366843/edit-rejected-for-adding-extra-information-beyond-single-character-typo) (then some privileged user performed a 1-character edit... the character minimum and practice of rejecting large edits creates a catch-22 for unprivileged users.)

And this time I didn't introduce new information other than mentioning the language used in the ***answer*** (so there is no reason my post should've been rejected).

Comment: i don't care how many downvotes i get, i'm right and stack overflow is only hurting itself by allowing objectively wrong answers to remain uncorrected.

Comment: Write your own correct answer.

Comment: If you're so convinced what you did is right, why did you bother posting a "discussion" question, then?

Comment: Stack Overflow model allows for these mistakes to be corrected by other users. Get a bit more rep and you can lend a hand as well.

Comment: @Cerbrus i would use "support", but the description says it's for people asking for help learning the system, not fixing questions.

Comment: You are fixating on the wrong angle. These "small edits to to reduce noise" **are** allowed. You are only hitting a limitation of the review queue that applies to for users with less reputation. Not a huge hurdle to jump over, if you are this commited to improve the site's quality.

Comment: You also shouldn't worry that much about rejected edits. The rejections _are_ gonna happen. There's nothing you can do about that. Just move on and fix the next question / answer.

Comment: What is your intention of this post? What is your question?

Answer (score 11):

Please understand that a large number of inexperienced editors do make unnecessary or inappropriate changes to code in existing answers, many of them minor edits, and the system has these limitations and policies in place to curb such edits. Allowing those through is far more detrimental to the site than not letting the unfortunately relatively few legitimate edits such as yours through, and reviewers have no choice but to err on the side of caution. I do find the choice of rejection reason bizarre, though none of the canned reasons fits this situation completely.

Compounding the problem is that if a subject matter expert were to step up and approve your edit I'm sure that you'll both just get lynched for "not following the rules". Meta can be a viciously black-and-white place like that. It's not like the other changes you made to "work around the character limit" were actively destructive to the post. However, I have seen more than my fair share of edits that did actually make inappropriate changes for the sake of meeting the character limit, such as introducing writing errors, adding excessive punctuation or formatting (the two most common by far), duplicating lines, and even adding gibberish. So, again, erring on the side of caution.

As mentioned, the easiest way around this is to

- settle for using comments to point out these errors and hope that the author or someone else will step up to fix it
- focus on suggesting edits that are less controversial for the time being
- until you reach 2000 reputation, at which point you're basically trusted "enough" to make good edits (though of course this hasn't stopped everyone from making bad edits that go unapproved, but the idea is there)

It's unfortunate that this is the state of affairs, but small (I won't say minor) suggested edits and their reviews have been a point of contention for both parties for as long as I can remember.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think your edit is wrong on itself, and I would have probably skipped it myself (since I would have needed to check that the change you made was actually correct, and that answer was not correct when it was posted, read the question too to confirm, etc; a lot of work to review a suggested edit).

And **making unnecessary changes to circumvent the 6 chars limitation rubs me the wrong way**. Superflous changes to circumvent sytem imposed limitations are not the way to go. Just work your way so the limitations no longer apply. Even if your superflous changes are not breaking changes, need to be reviewed, and reviewers may not appreciate that.

In the end, **many reviewers dislike seeing changes in code**. This kind of edit take more effort to review, can have unintended side-effects, etc.

And you've encountered this in the past. If I were you, instead of keep insisting that the rest of the site adjust to the way you think it should work, **I would wait until you hit 2k rep to make these edits**.

Or simply point out this type of errors in comments. Other users with more reputation or even the OP can correct the problems then. That is the important thing, right? Not that one specific suggested edit gets approved or not.

If you continue suggesting edits like these, they'll get rejected with some regularity.

Comment: stack overflow's self-destructive and counterproductive ruleset (specifically 6-character minimum, in conjunction with the relatively reasonable review system) is the problem

Comment: @jimbo1qaz: If Stack Overflow's ruleset is so self-destructive, wouldn't SO have self-destructed, by now?

Comment: it doesn't explode, it just stagnates, like the answer i linked to.

Comment: The rules is what separates SO from other free-form Q/A sites. Here, you'll find a much better signal:noise ratio.

Comment: more small edits to fix answers creates better-quality answers without small mistakes. in what way does repairing *broken* answers create noise or reduce signal?

Comment: @jimbo1qaz people make mistakes, what if it's not broken? Write your own answer, or add a comment to the existing answer. If you're right that will get upvotes and the "wrong" answer will get downvotes. If not, you didn't screw up a valid answer for everyone else.

Comment: @jimbo1qaz: These editing / review restrictions are in place to prevent unexperienced users from simply _breaking_ content. It's a unwritten rule on SO that suggested edits shouldn't change code. If the code is broken, explain so in a comment on the answer.

Comment: "It's a unwritten rule on SO that suggested edits shouldn't change code." if it's unwritten it shouldn't be a rule unless it's written down. it's bureaucratic to reject edits without saying there's such a "rule".

Comment: Unwritten rules just... "happen". And honestly, it works.

Comment: if there is no official policy prohibiting editing code. either it should be codified (prohibited or discouraged), or people should stop rejecting edits (assuming they contribute towards me getting edit-banned).

Comment: i will be seriously pissed when I eventually get edit-banned, having done nothing wrong and violated no rules. How easy or difficult is it to get edit-banned and is it intended as punishment?

Comment: If you have so much trouble adjusting to the community rules, I wouldn't be surprised if you encounter some kind of penalty box or another at some point. But I'm not sure a mod would want to edit ban you because of stuff like this. Again, a simpler, safer, better solution: you learn to work with all the rest, not against all the rest.

Comment: @jimbo1qaz: It is all too easy if you continue making edits knowing they are likely to get rejected, even if you disagree with the rejections. There are more constructive ways to address this than getting yourself banned. These bans are meant to get editors to slow down and review their editing methodology - they aren't intended as punishment unless the editor is acting in bad faith or something (which you aren't).

Comment: This question is a bit of a tempest in a teapot -- rejections happen, reviewers can be wrong, etc. etc. -- but what the fluff is going in this comment thread?? We're seriously telling someone that a vague meta guideline -- that really is directed at **question** edits anyways -- trumps having correct information on the site? **Minor fixes like this are the _raison d'etre_ of Stack Overflow's editing feature**. All of you defending the rejection of this edit, please remember this the next time _you're_ searching for a solution and it turns out to be subtly wrong.